# how to use ajax to populate Google search result in container on Django

Tags: python, ajax, django

I'm looking to make something like https://www.wolframalpha.com/ except with just vanilla Google. I'd like to have the Google results populate and pop out from the container.

My index will just have something like this:

```
<form action="search" method="get">
    <label for="query">Your Query: </label>
    <input id="myapp" type="text" name="myapp" value="Enter your query here">
    <input type="submit" value="search">
</form>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
    </body>
</html>
```

urls.py:
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

```
urlpatterns = [
    #url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', include('myapp.urls')),
    (r'^search/$', views.search),
]
```

views.py:

```
def search(query):
    #perform Google search and return the results
    return 1
```

I have a generic setup for non-ajax search as shown above. How would I incorporate ajax here?

Comment: just invoke ajax when the submit button is clicked. Don't know why you want to use ajax..

Comment: @AvinashRaj it can be anything, as long as it accomplishes what I need. Is there something else besides ajax?

Comment: first parameter of your search function should be `request`. see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/views/ . and get the sent data using `request.GET`